# Change "name" attribute of input element using for-loop, array, and eventListener - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Okay, so I have the following line of **Javascript** for which I'm trying to use to change the `name` attribute of an `input` element, following a *click* on a `div` element seperate from the `input` element.

Because I wish for the `name` attribute of the `input` element to change multiple times following separate *clicks*, I have attempted a `for` loop as seen below.

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('textinput').name = letters[i];
    }
  });
```

This code is successful in changing the `name` attribute of the element with `id` *textinput*, however, it automatically changes it to **e**, and does not cycle through the `for` loop, despite however many clicks are performed.

I am unsure on the issue and have had difficulty finding a suitible solution here on stackOverflow, so any answers to this issue are deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop you have will cycle through entirely each time, meaning that it will always end on `e`.

Instead, you'll want to increment the letter clicked on *each* time, and ensure that if it reaches the end of the array, it cycles back around to the start.

```js
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var textInput = document.getElementById("textinput");
var i = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() { 
  var letter = letters[i];
  textInput.name = letter;
  console.log(letter);
  
  if (++i >= letters.length) i = 0;
});
```

```html
<div id="btn">Click here!</div>
<input id="textinput">
```

Answer (score 3):

Your entire `for` loop will be executed on every click, leaving the `name` attribute to the last value of your array (`"e"`).

What you need is to increment the offset of your array at every click, something like:

```
var i = 0;
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('textinput').name = letters[i];
});
```

Comment: This is Ok for some extent. but it will give error on fifth click.

Answer (score 0):

To be more efficient, store your `letters` array, `input` element and `index` outside of the event handler:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var textinput = document.getElementById("textinput");
var index = 0;
```

To cycle through each element of the `letters` array, set the `.name` property using the value of the current `index` and increment it:

```
textinput.name = letters[index++];
```

To make sure you don't access the index of your array, that is `undefined`, use some boundary guard:

```
if (index >= letters.length) {
  index = 0;
}
```

```js
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var textinput = document.getElementById("textinput");
var index = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() { 
  textinput.name = letters[index++];    
  
  if (index >= letters.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  
  console.log(textinput.name);
});
```

```html
<input id="textinput" type="text"/>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Why add jQuery though?

Comment: Thanks @SamHolmes! Must have been a misplaced click in the code editor, corrected now.